# Why my material inputs are not working correclty on angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

my material inputs are not working properly. I think im missing an import maybe? because i just copy the example in the doc.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SUEs.png)

this is my appmodule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ContactComponent } from './Components/contact/contact.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgbModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My contact.component.ts is the default and the html is the same as the doc, just like this

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
  <input matInput />
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option value="one">First option</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="two">Second option</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>
  <textarea matInput></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have not imported any theme, if so then import any prebuilt theme in the styles.css

```css
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

check [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme) for more information